# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' even when matplotlib is installed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't seem to import matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Trying conda list matplotlib give the following output:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
matplotlib                3.1.1                    py37_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.1.1            py37h2852a4a_1    conda-forge
```

I tried to install it using pip: pip install matplotlib. It resulted in:

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (41.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
```

What should I do?

Edit: I later found that i could import it in my base env. But still can't do it in tf-gpu env

Comment: When you call `python -c "import matplotlib"` you get an error? Can you show the exact code ([mcve]) and how you run it?

Comment: What does `where python` result in?

Comment: @MadPhysicist C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\python.exe
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\yatin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried editing my answer. Is it better now? Please informing me if some other changes are required. (i am kinda of a noob)

Comment: Your first edit makes much more sense. So `python -c "import matplotlib"` called within the same environment results in the error. This is clearly unexpected.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest "This is clearly unexpected"; yep exactly. I have absolutely no idea what to do here :-(